# How to replace last free space to nbsp in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing

How I can replace last free space to `&nbsp;` in **ruby**?

I have in database this:

```html
<h1>Hello dear friend!</h1>
<p>How are you?</p>
<figure><img src="..." alt="..." /></figure>
<p>Bye!</p>
```

And I need to have this "output":

```html
<h1>Hello dear&nbsp;friend!</h1>
<p>How are&nbsp;you?</p>
<figure><img src="..." alt="..." /></figure>
<p>Bye!</p>
```

---

I tried to play with nokogiri:

```rb
text = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(...)
text.css('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, li').each do |tag|
  tag_arr = tag.content.split(' ')
  tag_last_words = tag_arr[tag_arr.length-2..tag_arr.length]
  tag_return = tag_arr[0..-2].push(tag_last_words.join('&nbsp;'))
  tag_return = tag_return.join(' ')
  tag.content = tag_return
end
```

but the I can't beat some "bugs":

- all attributes and inner tags (html) are deleted
- instead of `&nbsp;` I have `&amp;nbsp;`

---

Why? To avoid single word wrapping to new line on mobile device. (JS is not an option in my case)

Comment: Could you share the reason why you'd like to encode a space into &nbsp;? It's quite a difficult use case, since it will create a lot of overhead when you use Nokogiri for this purpose.

Comment: `tag_return = tag_arr[0..-2].push(tag_last_words.join('&nbsp;').gsub('&amp;nbsp;', '&nbsp;'))`

Comment: @bo-oz To avoid single word wrapping to new line on mobile device. (JS is not an option in my case)